# GridViewRow constructor parameters, What are they exactly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridviewrow

I have read the definition from msdn (see below) which did not help me. I am dynamically adding gridviewrows to my gridview and don't know what are the parameters for.

```
public GridViewRow(
    int rowIndex,
    int dataItemIndex,
    DataControlRowType rowType,
    DataControlRowState rowState
)
```

> **rowIndex Type**: System.Int32 The index of the GridViewRow object in the
>   Rows collection of a GridView control.
>
> **dataItemIndex Type**: System.Int32 The index of the DataItem in the
>   underlying DataSet.
>
> **rowType Type**: System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType One of the
>   DataControlRowType enumeration values.
>
> **rowState Type**: System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowState A bitwise
>   combination of the DataControlRowState enumeration values.

Comment: rowindex will give you current inserted row in gridview

Comment: @user1102001 and adding that as a parameter, how does that affect a newly created gridviewrow?

Comment: there are many ways to add rows to gridview but rowindex will not need for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These parameters (and this constructor in general) really rarely need to be used.  They are for creating a GridView, and it's rows, completely manually - something that's pretty unnecessary, considering the powerful databinding functionality that's built in to this control.  Let me explain.

Generally, you should construct a datasource (DataTable, some generic list of a custom class, etc) and then assign that datasource to the GridView and bind it.  This automates things like setting the RowIndex and DataItemIndex.  It also allows for a number of other convenient features (sorting, paging, editing / deleting).  See the [GridView Web Server Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s019wc0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
 for a great breakdown of this default functionality.

Thus, I would say that you should add the new row to your datasource (whatever that may be), then set the updated datasource to your GridView's DataSource property, and call `GridView.DataBind()`.  You'll have your new row, and won't have to mess with creating GridViewRow objects manually.

But, to answer your question:

- `int rowIndex`: The index (position) the row you're creating will occupy in the GridView.
- `int dataItemIndex`: The index of the of this data in your underlying data source (the DataTable or generic list or whatever it is your using).
- `DataControlRowType rowType`: This is the type of row - a row with data, a header, a footer, etc ([full list here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowtype.aspx)).
- `DataControlRowState rowState`: The "state" the row is in - edit mode, read only mode, etc ([full list here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowstate.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

```
  for example to add into gridview you can use datatable...

        public static DataTable TBCONRCVD;      

        FindRowNo = GoodsRcvdGridview.Items.Count;
        DataRow ROW = TBCONRCVD.NewRow();

        ROW["PRDCT_RCVD_PRDCT_CODE"] = TxtSearch.Text;
        ROW["PRDCT_RCVD_QTY"] = txtQty.Text.Trim();
        ROW["PRDCT_RCVD_COST"] = TXTUNITPRCE.Text.Trim();
        ROW["PRDCT_CRNT_SLNG_PRCE"] = SELL_PRCE.ToString();
        ROW["PRDCT_RCVD_VAT_CODE"] = TXTVATCODE.Text.Trim();
        ROW["PRDCT_RCVD_DISC"] = txtDscntPrcntge.Text;


        TBCONRCVD.Rows.Add(ROW);
        GoodsRcvdGridview.DataSource = TBCONRCVD;
        GoodsRcvdGridview.DataBind();
```